# Error deploying polymerCli to firebase

Tags: polymer, firebase-storage

I am learning polymer and firebase and I have a small proyect with polymerCli wich works fine localy (localhost) but when I deploy it to firebase I dont know why have this error: VM57 my-app.html:53 GET https://nutricion1-b22f8.firebaseapp.com/src/my-__.html 404 (Not Found)

does anyone know why this happend?

Thanks a lot